# Swift UIBarButtonItems not centered in UIToolbar using .flexibleSpace

Tags: swift, uikit, uitoolbar

In my UIKit App, i setup a UIToolbar with 5 Buttons like this:

```swift
class BrowserToolbar: UIToolbar {
  let goBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
  let goForwardButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
  let shareButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
  let bookmarkButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "book"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
  let tabsButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "square.on.square"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
  
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    // If toolbar frame size is not set then autolayout breaks so we need to set it manually
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59700020/layout-constraint-errors-with-simple-uitoolar-for-keyboard-inputaccessoryview
      super.init(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)))
    setupButtons()
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

```swift
private extension BrowserToolbar {
  func setupButtons() {
    items = [
      goBackButton,
      UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
      goForwardButton,
      UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
      shareButton,
      UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
      bookmarkButton,
      UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
      tabsButton
    ]
  }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the buttons are not correctly centered. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you run the app and share an image of captured view hierarchy?

Comment: @birkoof if you want, you can also test the app yourself. It's an open source project: https://github.com/amerhukic/Browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system images aren't of the same size, so the flexible space just fills up the space between the buttons and the buttons only use up the width provided by the image.

From view hierarchy:

[image]

If you use the same image for all UIBarButtons you will see that they are properly aligned:

[image]

So the solution would be either to create your own image assets of the same size, or to find a way to give the images fixed width inside of the UIBarButton. There are [some SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073738/change-size-of-uibarbuttonitem-image-in-swift-3) that explain this but I haven't tried it out.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i ended up, using a fixed width on my `UIBarButtonItem`, in my case `48` like `toolbarButton.width = 48`. I don't know if it's the best solution, but it seems to work.